# How to use iFunbox software for my computer to transfer CoC data

Tags: ios, game-center, clash-of-clans

I'm wondering how to transfer my Clash of Clans (CoC) data from one iOS device to another.

My gamecenter is really messed up so I need a new way to transfer CoC data. Can [iFunbox](http://www.i-funbox.com/) (or other utilities that read iOS storage filesystem) help me with that?

Comment: If you want to edit in specific requirements - like what version of the game you want to move data and/or what computer you have access to for moving the data (assuming that the game allows save files to be moved in the manner you assume - the data could be tied to one device encrypted or saved in the cloud to avoid cheating)

Comment: So... you know how to? :)